# Refreshing display on every movement(velocity) (openGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, game-physics

In Opengl have this function `dance()` that I want to move an object and refresh the screen and then move again, so that it looks like the object is constantly moving. Right now all it does is move alot, and then refreshes the screen.

This is my displ ay_Main:

```
void window::main () {
 static int argc = 0;
 glutInit (&argc, nullptr);
 glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
 glutInitWindowSize (window::width, window::height);
 glutInitWindowPosition (128, 128);
 glutCreateWindow (sys_info::execname().c_str());
 glutCloseFunc (window::close);
 glutEntryFunc (window::entry);
 glutDisplayFunc (window::display);
 glutReshapeFunc (window::reshape);
 glutKeyboardFunc (window::keyboard);
 glutSpecialFunc (window::special);
 glutMotionFunc (window::motion);
 glutPassiveMotionFunc (window::passivemotion);
 glutMouseFunc (window::mousefn);
 glutMainLoop();
 }
```

This is my display code:

```
void window::display() {
 glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 for (auto& object: window::objects) object.draw();
 objects.at(selected_obj).draw_border();
 mus.draw();
 glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

This is my move code:

```
 void move (GLfloat delta_x, GLfloat delta_y) {
     //center pertains to the object that is drawn
     center.xpos += delta_x;
     center.ypos += delta_y;
  }
```

And now my Dance code:

```
  static void dance(){
     int x =0; int y=0;
     for(;;){
       int r1 = rand() % 100;
       int r2 = rand() %100;
       vertex v = objects.at(selected_obj).get_vertex();
       if(v.xpos >= width) break;
       if(v.ypos >= height) break;
       x=move_pixels+r1; y=move_pixels+r2;
       objects.at(selected_obj).move(x,y);
       glutPostRedisplay();
      }
    }
```

In my `dance()` I want it to move and then update, and then move again(like velocity). However, it just moves all at once and updates when its done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glutPostDisplay` just sets a flag, that upon the next iteration of the event loop the display function should be called.

Here's the most important rule of event driven programming: **Never** put timed actions, like animations into a "playback" loop that cycles through the whole animation before returning to the event system. In your case you've to break down your `dance` function into an *idle* function, that gets called every time all pending events (including redraw) have been processed. Then you can advance to the next step update the animation and issue a redraw.

Comment: the way I have it set up right now is that `move()` is called whenever an arrow on the keyboard is pressed. So how would I call the `move()` multiple times without using a loop, so that it simulates consecutive movement?

Comment: @Lou: With glutIdleFunc you can register a function that's being called whenever nothing else is left to do. The inner loop of your `dance` function (without the actual loop) would be perfect fit for idle. Of course you'll have to put the state into global variables. In the event handlers set flags that control the idle operation. Another approach would be to ditch GLUT and instead use a framework where you've got direct control over the event loop.